# Detecting objects within frame’s camera FOV

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, camera, eevee-render-engine

In Blender 2.80 EEVEE how to enumerate a list of all objects it has to render in a given animation frame? Alternatively how to test if a known plane is in the FOV on a given animation frame? Thanks!